# Anybody can tell me what is the encoding type of these characters?

Tags: javascript, xml, character-encoding

I have a script using these characters and i want to know what type of encoding they have.
The main problem is when i try to convert them to XML they are being ignored.
Any solution?
Thank you in advance for your time.

[image]

Comment: See the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets): character `\u2` is outside of the supported range, as is `\x07`.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with encoding. If the text includes the characters with code points 2 and 7, then they can't be included in an XML 1.0 document. (It sounds as if your conversion tool ignores characters that aren't invalid in XML, other tools might throw an error, or find some other way of representing them for example as a processing instruction `<?char 2?>`).

XML 1.1 allows these code points, but XML 1.1 isn't widely supported.